# Crystal Report - detail section increment horizontally according to Order number

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

I HAVE ATTACHED IMAGE FILE( Table Structure and Details need in crystal report). I crystal report detail section as based on NO(1,3,4) (which having Y) [Crystal Report table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jCHR.jpg)

Comment: May you review your post and make clear what is your question?

Comment: GRP_DESCRIPTION and GRP_DESC column which were retrieved according to grouping GRP_DESCRIPTION . In values section , For GRP_DESCRIPTION (PASTE)  we have GRP_DESC  (COL1) which has 'Y' value For NO 1,3,4. And for GRP_DESC  (COL2) which has 'Y' value For NO 1,3,4 and so on.. I need is  IN VALUE SECTION, for which NO has value 'Y' Need to be increased horizontally